# Can't run more than one NgTestBed in one angular dart test

Tags: unit-testing, angular, dart

I have two test methods in one file. However when I run them the last one fails.

When I try to debug the test inside the browser after the first `answer.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));` executes the event listeners on the second row won't activate as if they weren't able to listen to any click events. I tried clicking manually as well and the rows didn't change color like the first row (using the exact same code).

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
import 'package:angular_test/angular_test.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

import '...multiple_choice_quiz_component.dart';

@AngularEntrypoint()
void main()
{
    tearDown(disposeAnyRunningTest);

    group('$MultipleChoiceQuizComponent', () {
        test('should add "incorrect" css class to incorrect answer', () async {
            NgTestBed bed = new NgTestBed<MultipleChoiceQuizComponent>();
            NgTestFixture fixture = await bed.create();
            Element answer = fixture.rootElement.querySelector('.quiz-choice:nth-child(2)');
            answer.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
            bool hasClass = answer.classes.contains('incorrect');
            expect(hasClass, true);
        });

        test('should add "correct" css class to correct answer', () async {
            NgTestBed bed = new NgTestBed<MultipleChoiceQuizComponent>();
            NgTestFixture fixture = await bed.create();
            Element answer = fixture.rootElement.querySelector('.quiz-choice:nth-child(3)');
            answer.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
            bool hasClass = answer.classes.contains('correct');
            expect(hasClass, true);
        });
    });

}
```

Here is a screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

The first row is the first test method. `answer.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));` executes correctly and the color changes.

However on the second row with the exact same code the whole second row is unresponsive. Like I said it's almost as if the event listeners for the second row are disabled.

In fact, if I put the two methods in different `dart` test files **both tests pass**.

Why can't I have these two tests in one file?

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a bug where `disposeAnyRunningTest` doesn't actually do what we want.

https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_test/issues/46

This is why it behaves differently for you when you have the test cases in separate files, but doesn't work when they run together.

The tests might not work when they aren't properly disposed for a few reasons.

- The component you are testing might have a bug which does not allow multiple copies on the page at once. Do you use element ids anywhere that might make them only work when there is a single instance?
- `Fixture.rootElement` might have a bug which is causing it to return the element from the previous test instead of the new one.